# node app on debian: how to escape backslash

Tags: json, node.js, debian, backslash

How to escape backslashes has been answered here many times - but I experienced a strange behaviour when trying to load a config file on a DEBIAN machine when starting my node application:

ldapconfig.json

```
{"username" : "XYZ\\ldapread_user1"}
```

in my app.js:

```
var ldapconfig = require(process.cwd() + '/ldapconfig.json');
var config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ldapconfig));
console.log(config);
```

i get following output:

```
 {"username" : "XYZ\\ldapread_user1"}
```

instead of the expected:

```
 {"username" : "XYZ\ldapread_user1"}
```

using only one backslash will obviously produce a JSON parse error.

when trying to do it via a ldapconfig.js file:

```
module.exports={username : "XYZ\\ldapread_user1"}
```

and call it like

```
var ldapconfig = require(process.cwd() + '/ldapconfig.js');
console.log(ldapconfig);
```

I get

```
{"username" : "XYZ\\ldapread_user1"}
```

again, using a single bnackslash results in that being escaped..

I have the same unexpected behaviour - how can i get a single backslash?